# Setup simple email forwarding and smtp server for app

Tags: email, dedicated-server

I've moved one of my web sites over to a dedicated server. I'd like to move all my other sites over as I can pretty much do everything I need to do, except setup an email server. This is usually a pretty complicated task from everything I've read about postfix.

Email setup is the one thing holding me back. I already have MX records setup at the registrar for my domain.

I have really only a few requirements:

1. I don't need inboxes on the server at all, nor do I want to be responsible for that risk. There will not be an associated "user" on the server that maps to an email address (ex: info@mydomain.com -> me@gmail.com)
2. I only need to setup email aliases for hosted domains that forward to another email account (like me@mydomain.com -> me@gmail.com)
3. I DO need to have an SMTP server running w/ authentication so my web app can send out  email notifications to its users using my email server.

I'm really trying to ween myself off shared/cloud hosting, but the email setup I require is the only thing holding me back from being 100% self-sufficient.

What's the easiest way to setup postfix to do aliases and smtp server? Everything I've read pretty much assumes you need to do inbox hosting, w/ mysql and web interface, etc, which I don't need. I've looked into Google Business as recommended in other threads, but I would rather learn how to do it for free than pay Google to do it.